# Error relate SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem: when we run the code, it displays the following error:

> There are primary keys or candidates in the reference `Ticket` table 
>   that match the list of referencing columns in foreign key '
>   `FK__Payment__PkTicke__1A14E395`

Code:

```
create table SystemUser
(
    PkUser int identity(1,1),
    UserLogin nvarchar(20) not null unique,
    UserPassword nvarchar(50) not null,
    UserName nvarchar(50) not null,
    UserCpf nvarchar(50) not null,
    UserBirth datetime not null,
    UserGender nvarchar(15) not null,
    AddressCep int not null,
    AddressStreet nvarchar(50) not null,
    AddressNumber nvarchar(20) not null,
    AddressComplement nvarchar(50) not null,
    AddressCity nvarchar(50) not null,
    AddressState nvarchar(50) not null,
    primary key(PkUser)
)

create table Attractions
(
    PkAttraction integer identity(1,1) ,
    AttractionName nvarchar(50) not null unique,
    AttractionDate datetime not null,
    AttractionDescription nvarchar(150) not null
    primary key(PkAttraction)
)

create table Ticket
(
    PkTicket int identity(1,1),
    PkUser int not null,
    PkAttraction int not null,
    TicketPrice decimal not null,
    primary key(PkTicket, PkUser, PkAttraction),
    foreign key(PkUser) references SystemUser(PkUser),
    foreign key(PkAttraction) references Attractions(PkAttraction)
)   

create table Payment
(
    PkPayment int identity(1,1),
    PkTicket int not null,
    Portion int not null,
    IdTransaction nvarchar(100) not null,
    Payday datetime not null,
    primary key(PkPayment, PkTicket),
    foreign key(PkTicket) references Ticket(PkTicket),
)       

create table FormPayment
(
    PkFromPayment int identity(1,1),
    PkPayment int not null,
    ShareValue decimal not null,
    ExpirationDate datetime not null
    primary key(PkFromPayment, PkPayment),
    foreign key(PkPayment) references Payment(PkPayment),
)
```

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Ticket` table as a primary key made up from 3 columns:

```
create table Ticket
(
    .....
    primary key(PkTicket, PkUser, PkAttraction),
    ....
)
```

Any table that wants to reference that table Ticket **must also** provide **all 3 columns** for the foreign key.

You **cannot** reference only part of a primary key - if you want to reference it, you **must have** all columns that it contains - otherwise you cannot establish a FK relationship.

So you must add the `PkUser` and `PkAttraction` columns to your `Payment` table so that you can establish this FK relationship:

```
create table Payment
(
    PkPayment int identity(1,1),
    PkTicket int not null,
    PkUser int not null,          // add this
    PkAttraction int not null,    // add this
    Portion int not null,
    IdTransaction nvarchar(100) not null,
    Payday datetime not null,
    primary key(PkPayment, PkTicket),

    // change to this
    foreign key(PkTicket, PkUser, PkAttraction) references Ticket(PkTicket, PkUser, PkAttraction)
    .....
)
```

Comment: Thank you!
Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you not specify a name for FK and PK, SQL server generates a name. in this case, looks like SQL server generates duplicate name. 
If you specify name for FK and PK, it will work.